# How to use uuid from firebase in react js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, uuid

I write code as you can see below in reactjs and used firebase for uuid.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    var firebase = require('firebase');
    var uuid = require('firebase');
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "PRIVATE",
        authDomain: "Private.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://Private.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "Private",
        storageBucket: "Private.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "Private"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    export default class Usurvey extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          **uid: uuid.v1(),**
          studentName: '',
          answers: {
            answer1 : '',
            answer2 : '',
            answer3 : ''
          },
          isSubmitted: false
        };
      }
      render(){
        var studentName;
        var questions;

        if (this.state.studentName === '' && this.state.isSubmitted === false) {
        }

        return(
          <div>
          {studentName}
          -------------------------
          {questions}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

but after run, this page has shown 
**TypeError: uuid.v1 is not a function**

> 24 |   uid: uuid.v1(),

As you can see I used this function in my code but send me a problem.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you use like this ->> firebase.UserInfo.uid  or firebase.User.uid instead of uuid.v1()  and tell me what happens

Comment: Its right and I am not getting error yet>> firebase.User.uid

Comment: did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes thanks, I am not getting error yet

Comment: accept the answer so it can help others

Comment: after running not getting uid: undefined

Comment: uid only works when the user logins. have you created any login fucntionality

Answer (score -1):

use `firebase.User.uid` to avoid the error